# CSS issue with 'overflow-y:auto' that creates a problem in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser

In my app, text is inputted by the user and is displayed within a div with a fixed width and height and a `overflow-y:auto` property. The html looks like this:

```
<div class="description_div scroll-pane jspScrollable" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 290px; " tabindex="0">
    <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 290px; height: 160px; ">
        <div class="jspPane" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; width: 280px; left: 0px; ">
           <p>This is an original song written and performed by me, Jessica Speziale. I wrote this in early May 2011 :) Let me know what you think!</p>
           <p>Studio is 3 DAYS AWAY!!!  *dies*  I’ll be sending daily studio blogs via my newsletter!  Also, if you sign-up for the newsletter before August 31st, you’ll be entered to win a free copy of my EP!  Woot!! </p>
           <p>Sign up here: http://www.reverbnation.com/page_object/join_mailing_list/artist_868563</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer div is the one I specify, and all of the other divs are dynamically generated with the [jscrollpane plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/). Here is the css for the outer div:

```
.description_div{
    float:right;
    width:280px;
    height:160px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

The problem is that this renders correctly in Firefox but not in Chrome. Here is a pic of how it is rendered in Firefox:

[image: Firefox-1]    [image: Firefox-2]

and here is how it is rendered in Chrome:

[image: Chrome-1]     [image: Chrome-2]

As you can see, in Firefox it cuts up the long url at the bottom of the div so that all the text fits within the width of the div, and a vertical scroll bar is added.

In Chrome, it cuts off the last paragraph of text on the bottom and only adds a horizontal scroll bar.

Why is this, and is there a solution to remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

The default wrapping algorithm in Firefox can insert line breaks at forward slashes, in Chrome it doesn't. You can add `word-wrap: break-word;` style to the outer div to force wrapping however. Make sure that `padding-right` isn't set to 0 (from your code example it isn't clear whether it currently is) or some text will be invisible because of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try a full on overflow:auto. None of this -y or -x business, unless you need to have different settings.

Comment: doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Scroll Bars are ugly any ways... why not animate it using css like here: http://www.nikesh.me/blog/2010/05/sexy-image-hover-effects-using-css3/
Have it enlage, slide the text over, or something else fun.